# Calling toArray() on a synchronized array list a thread safe operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am creating and using a synchronized array list which is being accessed/modified by multiple threads. In a certain operation I want to remove all elements of this synchronized list and process them.

```
List<String> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

// adding to array
public void addElements(String s) {
   myList.add(s)
}

public void removeAllAndProcess() {
  Arrays.stream(myList.toArray()).forEach(s -> {
            myList.remove(s);
            process(s.toString());
        });
}

// Some processing
public void process(String s) {
  // if processing unsuccessful then again add to list : myList.add(s)
}
```

I am wondering if `toArray()` needs to be within a synchronized block ? Will a concurrent addition to the list while `toArray` is being called will affect the returned array ?

Comment: Must it be a `List`?

Comment: Does tho `process` method delete the element from the list? Or is it that you *only* call `process` from within `removeAllAndProcess`, and never call `process` outside that method?

Comment: ```process``` is being called by another thread as well. (in conclusion its maybe called by 2 threads at the same time but since the List is synchronized the add operation should be thread safe). ```process``` does not remove anything from the list but if the processing for an element is unsuccessful then it will add to ```myList```. My main concern is with ```toArray()```, and if a call to this function needs to be synchronized.

Comment: Well that lacking detail ruins my Answer. You should make such points clear *before* posting.

Comment: Perhaps your Question would have been better asked without any example code. The simple question "Is `List#toArray` on a `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` object thread-safe?" is indeed an interesting one. I could not decipher the Javadoc nor the source code to directly answer that.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the inconvenience. I did try to mention that multiple threads will access/modify the list. The main objective of my question was to see if ```toArray``` is thread safe. I did look into the code myself and when I saw ```System.arrayCopy``` I stopped. I was hoping to run into an ```iterator``` or ```spliterator``` cause then I would know that I definitely have to manually synchronize it.

Comment: Rather than a `List`, why not use a concurrent [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) with its `drainTo` method?

Comment: I dont want the thread to be blocked if the queue is empty when ```removeAllAndProcess``` is called. I am considering ```ConcurrentLinkedQueue``` as well

Comment: I see that ```drainTo``` is not a blocking call. I think I can use that then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No additional synchronisation is needed as `Collections.synchronizedList(xyz)` wraps all access to underlying `xyz` safely.

You could double check your JDK implementation by following the source code in a good IDE. In OpenJDK20 you will see that `Collections.synchronizedList` returns a `SynchronizedList`

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<>(list) :
            new SynchronizedList<>(list));
}
```

`SynchronizedList` extends `SynchronizedCollection` which implements `toArray()` with object synchronisation to ensure that you have thread-safe operation:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    synchronized (mutex) {return c.toArray();}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for `Collections.synchronizedList` says:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when traversing it via Iterator, Spliterator or Stream

I do not know if we should consider that prescription to apply to `List#toArray`. I would have assumed so, but apparently not.

I went to look at the source code at OpenJDK for `ArrayList` [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java). Apparently `ArrayList#toArray` implementation is:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
}
```

The source code of `Arrays.copyOf` ends up calling `System.arrayCopy`.

So we have a pile of code. And none of it explicitly promises thread-safety. So while I cannot directly answer your Question, I can offer a simple alternative solution.

## `AtomicReference`

I would suggest this simple solution as an alternative: Rather than drain the list of elements, replace the entire list, while providing thread-safety with an [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

However, we need to synchronize on the `addElement` method with this approach. It would be possible for one thread to get a reference to the list, a second thread to replace the list with a new one and begin iteration on the old list, while the first thread modifies the old list to which it still has a reference.

While we must add synchronization to the `addElement` method, we can remove synchronization from the list itself. Under this approach we are no longer deleting from the list. The only modification we make to the list is adding through the now synchronized `addElement` method. So no need to call `Collections.synchronizedList`.

By the way, I changed the plural `addElements` to the singular `addElement`.

```java
AtomicReference < List < String > > myListRef = new AtomicReference( new ArrayList<>() ) ;

// adding to array
public synchronized void addElement( String s ) {
    myListRef.get().add( s ) ;
}

public void removeAllAndProcess() {
    List < String > newList = new ArrayList<>() ;
    List < String > oldList = myListRef.getAndSet( newList ) ;
    oldList.forEach( ( String s ) -> {
            myList.remove( s ) ;
            process( s );
        }
    );
}

// Some processing
public void process(String s) {
  boolean processedSuccessfully = … ;
  if( ! processedSuccessfully ) { 
    myListRef.get().add( s ) ;
  }
}
```

Note: My presumption here is that your `process` method is *only* ever called from within your `removeAllAndProcess` method.

---

I am not happy about the arrangement of your code. But I am ignoring such issues, to focus on your Question as asked.

I suspect another data structure such as a `Queue` would better suit your purposes. But, again, I am ignoring that to focus on your Question as asked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using a ```Queue```.

Comment: The `Collections.synchronizedList` call doesn't return `java.util.ArrayList`, it gives a List with a different implementation of `toArray()`